# Espresso ActivityTestRule doesn't work with AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso, android-instrumentation

I'm trying to create a UI test for my android application using Espresso. My activities are extending `AppCompatActivity` and I'm using `ActivityTestRule` to launch the activity but it gives this exception:

```
Type parameter bound for T in constructor ActivityTestRule<T : Activity (activityClass: Class<T!>!)is not satisfied: inferred type HomeActivity! is not a subtype of Activity!
```

Here's my test class:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class ProductListRestrictionsUITest {

    @Rule @JvmField
    var activityRule = ActivityTestRule(HomeActivity::class.java)

    @Test
    fun buttonClick_goToSecondActivity() {
        onView(withId(R.id.floatingSearchView)).perform(click())
        onView(withId(R.id.floatingSearchView)).perform(typeText("olut"))
        onView(withId(R.id.floatingSearchView)).perform(pressKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH))

//        onView(withId(R.id.layout)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    }
}
```

I have the required dependencies in the gralde file as well:

```
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'

// espresso support
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
```

I couldn't find any resource that says what other rule to use for `AppCompatActivity`. What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me on a separate module I created for my tests. I have a `base-android` module that hold my `BaseActivity` and did not import it on my tests module. As it cannot see the imported base activity, the test cannot see its super type. Importing the `base-android` module on my `tests` module fixed the issue.

Comment: Can you elaborate the answer?

Answer (score -1):

This can happen in a `com.android.test` module, when the versions of appcompat were different between the main app, and the test module.

Fix is to explicitly declare the appcompat dependency with version number in both `app/build.gradle` and `testmodule/build.gradle`, so you get the same version in both.

Comment: even different libraries (which are likely not the case) would both be sub-type of `Activity`... think that the third line of the error message (as I've formatted it) is a bogus error message (as the compiler sees it).